# SSL handshake error when downloading images

Tags: python, geojson, request, planet, ssl

I'm learning the Planet API and going through the tutorials posted online.  When I attempt to perform an image search, download, etc. I get an SSL handshake error.

Some example commands I am calling are from here: https://www.planet.com/docs/api-quickstart-examples/cli/

I get the following error:

> ```
> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.planet.com', 
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/v1/quick-search?
> _page_size=100 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL 
> routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify 
> failed')],)",),))
> ```

Downgrading my python libraries and turning SSL cert checking haven't worked.  I am using Python 3 on a Windows machine.

Comment: Try to downgrade pyOpenSSL to 17.3.0: pip install -U pyOpenSSL==17.3.0

Comment: Did you try telling `requests` to ignore the error? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445989/125400

Comment: Can you tell us something about the network you are on?

Comment: @DenVakxden Thanks for the idea, unfortunately no success

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Adding in a verify=false flag gave me the following error:    Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x042672D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',)))

Comment: @Alexander I am behind a corporate proxy

Comment: If you have a forward proxy, you usually have to specify the address. The documentation for how to do that using requests is here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: @Alexander I fixed it, thanks!  It was a problem with the Planet cert not being added to my certifi pem.